# No quotes in MongoDB JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am learning MongoDB. While JSON specification is like:

```
{"Website":"Stack overflow", "Popularity":"High"}
```

in Mongo JavaScript examples I see it like:

```
{
name: "David",
score: 0
}
```

I have tried the following example:

```
text = '{"name": "Wallie"}';
text2 ='{name: "Wallie"}'
```

`JSON.parse(text)` works well while `JSON.parse(text2)` gives `Syntax Error: Unexpected token`.

So why MongoDBs JSON is different?

Comment: MongoDB's examples are written in JavaScript, not in JSON.

Comment: What I am exactly following is "Make your First Meteor Application" book, which says in MongoDB part: 

"The data we pass through needs to be in the JSON format, and if you’re not familiar with the
JSON format, this is what it looks like:
{
name: "David",
score: 0
}"

Comment: are you using mongo shell? how are you executing the commands?

Comment: When you create an object in JavaScript, it's written like this: `{name: "David", score: 0}`, but it becomes `{"name": "David", "score": 0}` after `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: So actually you do not pass JSON to MongoDB but instead Javascript objects? And I should contact author of the book to correct the text?

Comment: @ibininja I have tried them in Chrome console, just to understand the way it works.

Comment: @Vladimir I added what I think is what you are inquiring about.

Comment: I would like to add that there is no such thing as "MongoDB's JSON". It is [BSON](http://bsonspec.org), which is a superset of JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is the following:

The following

```
{"Website":"Stack overflow", "Popularity":"High"}
```

is the complete way to create the queries with quotations over the keys and values.

this example

```
{name: "David",score: 0}
```

is acceptable if you are using **mongo shell** since quotes are implicit (again in mongo shell) and can be omitted; the shell will handle it for you. If you are not using the shell Quotes should be there as per JSON specs.

My advise is that to start with mongodb start from the shell than move out to any programming language that is supported by their drivers (java, python, js..etc)

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and I see that Mongo accepts both Javascript object and JSON notation, so now it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found solution at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-format

It's BSON not JSON, which MongoDB uses. It resembles JavaScript object notation and is compatible with JSON, hence the confusion.